# Mutar vídeos dentro de Slider com Youtube iFrame API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Estou com uma situação bizarra acontecendo.

Eu tenho um loop em PHP para consumir informações do banco e exibir na página. Uma dessas informações é o ID de um vídeo do Youtube que eu gostaria de exibir com autoplay e mudo.

Depois de bater muita cabeça, cheguei nesse código:

```
<?php include_once "common.php";?> <!-- dados de Conexão com o banco -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 0px;" class="bannerslider">
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY pkcodebanner DESC LIMIT 5";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $player = 0;
        $imagem = 0;
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                if($row['isvideo'] == 1){
                    echo '<iframe 
                            id="player'.$player.'"
                            class="yt-player"
                            width="999" 
                            height="370" 
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$row['video'].'?wmode=opaque&autohide=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0" 
                            frameborder="0" 
                            volume="0" 
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>';

                    $player++;
                } else {

                    echo '<div id="imagem'.$imagem.'" class="imgbanner" 
                    style="background-image: url(adm/CodeOutput/public/uploads/'.$row["imagem"].')"></div>';

                    $imagem++;
                };

            }
        } else {
            echo "Não há banners";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</div>

<style>
    .imgbanner{
        width: 999px;
        height: 370px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var players = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-player");
    var player;
    var pl = [];
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        for (i=0;i<players.length;i++){
            player = new YT.Player(players[i]['id'], {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
            pl.push(player);

        }
        console.log(pl);
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event){
        for (i=0;i<players.length;i++){
            pl[i].mute();
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Esse código funciona perfeitamente e pode ser visto funcionando aqui](http://www.vivaceescolademusica.com/vivace2017teste/banner.php)

O que rola é que eu preciso jogar isso tudo dentro de um slider pra fazer um banner rotativo.
Não tenho problemas em gerar o slider usando o [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) mas, quando eu adiciono o starter do slick pra criar o slider o JS pra mutar os vídeos para de funcionar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bannerslider').slick({
            infinite: true 
    }); 
});
```

Também depois de iniciar o Slick, ele cria 1 iframe a mais do que o original. Sem o slick, o console.log(pl) retorna 1 array com 2 objetos. Quando o Slick está ativo console.log(pl) retorna 1 array com 3 objetos. Eu imagino que ele criaria um objeto a mais de qualquer forma mas, como o iframe é o primeiro da lista, ele duplica o registro.

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como eu posso resolver essa situação?

Comment: eu odeio ser o cara chato que reclama das coisas ao invés de resolver, mas: já tentou usar outro slider?

Comment: Cara, já :(. Eu usei o BxSlider antes desse. Eu vou postar jájá uma resposta tb pq eu meio que consegui resolver, mas ta meio gambiarra, vou postar pra ver se alguém sugere algo.Valeu assim mesmo =D